# How can I store a part of my scrape in an np.array outside a for loop?

Tags: python

I scrape this website for ps4 games and I want to store the shipping data in a NumPy array outside the loop so I can get the games where shipping are less than 5.99 and free shipping. when I do it only print the first value of the game which is 'free shipping'.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url='https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Video-Games/SubCategory/ID-3141'
uClient=uReq(url)
page = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
#parsing
page_soup = soup(page, "html.parser")

#grabs products
containers= page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})
#file
filename = "products.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")
headers= 'brand, product, shipping\n'
f.write("headers")

   for container in containers:
     brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

     title = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
     productName= title[0].text

     shipping_container= container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
     shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()


     print("Brand: " + brand)
     print("Product: " + productName)
     print("Shipping: " + shipping)

     f.write(brand + ',' + productName.replace(',','|') + ',' + shipping + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: Are you dead set on using an np.array? This sounds like a job for pandas to me.

Comment: I'm down to use pandas too

Comment: Basically just create an empty pandas dataframe (I would put it right after importing packages), and then append a new row to the dataframe with the brand, product, and shipping information right where you print in the loop. Then, once the loop ends, you'll have a dataframe with all of the info you scraped.

Comment: thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend create a dict structure, which will be filled in a loop, and than create from this dict a dataframe. Here is an example:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import re

url='https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Video-Games/SubCategory/ID-3141'

with uReq(url) as uClient:
    page = uClient.read()

# parsing
page_soup = soup(page, "html.parser")

# grabs products
containers= page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

# file
filename = "products.csv"

d = defaultdict(list)

# fill dict
for container in containers:
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

    title = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title[0].text

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()
    
    d['brand'].append(brand)
    d['product'].append(product_name)
    d['shipping'].append(shipping)
    
# create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# clean shipping column
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Free Shipping' else x)
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Special Shipping' else x) # probably should be handled in a special way
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: x if x == 0 else re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x))
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].astype(float)

# save dataframe to csv file
df.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=False)

# choose rows where shipping is less than 5.99
print(df[df['shipping'] > 5.99])
```